# Spring boot Autowired annotation equivalent for .net core mvc

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, autowired

Question mentions it all.

In spring boot I am able to use the `AutoWired` annotation to *automagically* inject a dependency into my controller.

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    @AutoWired
    private SomeDependency someDependency;
}
```

For [asp.net-core-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) I am curious as to if it has this annotation, currently the way to do it is by adding it as an argument to the constructor

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private SomeContext _someContext;

    public SomeController(SomeContext someContext)
    {
        _someContext = someContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: I loved the "automagically"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no annotation.

You just need to make sure you register the dependency with the DI container at the composition root which is usually `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddScoped<SomeContext>();

    //...
}
```

If in your case `SomeContext` is a `DbContext` derived class then register it as such

```
var connection = @"some connection string";
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

When resolving the controller the framework will resolve known [explicit dependencies](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) and inject them.

Reference [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Reference [Dependency injection into controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection)

Comment: The default DI container basically only allows constructor injection, so all dependencies should be made constructor parameters.

Comment: @juunas is that comment meant for me or the OP?

Comment: An improvement suggestion for your answer :)

Comment: Since `@Autowired` in Spring does property injection, it might be significant to mention the difference.

Comment: @juunas that is why I was asking for confirmation. Your statement is not entirely accurate as it (the framework) allows *Action Injection* as well. Check the second link. I specifically made no mention of constructor injection because it was not the only option available.

Comment: Ahh, right that is true! You can inject into controller actions with `[FromServices]` and you can inject into middleware Invoke functions. You can ignore my comment :)

Comment: Yes I am aware of registering the context and have done so, I am mostly inquiring on ridding the controller with the constructors boiler plate code, the [FromService] is what I'm looking for but at a class member level

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NAutowired](https://github.com/FatTigerWang/NAutowired/blob/master/README_EN.md),the field injection

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` doesn't provide property setter injection (only constructor injection). However, you can achieve this by using the [Quickwire](https://github.com/flavien/quickwire) NuGet package, which does all the necessary plumbing for you. It extends the ASP.NET core built-in dependency injection container to allow service registration using attributes.

To use it, first add these two lines to your `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Activate controllers using the dependency injection container
    services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
    // Detect services declared using the [RegisterService] attribute
    services.ScanCurrentAssembly();

    // Register other services...
}
```

Then simply decorate your controller with the `[RegisterService]` attribute, and decorate any property to autowire with `[InjectService]`:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[RegisterService(ServiceLifetime.Transient)]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [InjectService]
    private SomeContext SomeContext { get; init; }
}
```

Now `SomeContext` will *automagically* get injected with the corresponding registered service without having to go through the constructor song and dance.

For more information, you can also check out [this table](https://github.com/flavien/quickwire#equivalence-with-spring-framework-in-java) that maps out which Quickwire attribute corresponds to which Spring Boot annotation.

Comment: Is Quickwire ready to use in a production environment?